# How to force Group Policy Management Console to send LDAP queries via 636 port

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, ldap

There is an [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd772723(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) stating that 636 port can be used by GPMC for secure communications.

Active Directory Certificate Services were installed successfully. Certificate from DC was exported to the workstation. LDP.exe tool as well as ADSIEdit on workstation are able to connect via 636 port.

However traffic analyzer shows that GPMC still uses port 389 for LDAP connections.

How can I force Group Policy Management Console to establish a secure connection via 636 port?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you reviewed [How to enable LDAP signing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/enable-ldap-signing-in-windows-server) ?

Comment: Sure, that is an option that forces DC to reject simple LDAP binds, with credentials sent as plain text. According to this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ne-iads-ads_authentication_enum there are options that allow you to send encrypted and signed traffic still using port 389, as GPMC does. I need to switch GPMC to use port 636. The only option I see here is to inject into GPMC and find out which exact flags it passes, when calling ADsOpenObject API. Just trying to find an easy way

Comment: This comes up occasionally. You cannot prevent Windows or Windows applications from using LDAP port 389.

Comment: I understand, however the documentation says that Group Policy can use 636. For example, I know that there is a registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AdminDebug\ADsOpenObjectFlags. In case if I set it to 3 all LDAP apps will stop using signing and encryption. Maybe there is some kind of an option to force LDAPS

Comment: I think that's just bad documentation. I've never seen the native administrative tools use LDAPS, much less force them to require it. It also would not help with the several other ports that it requires. I've never seen a true "need" for them to use port 636, these usually seem like bug hunts that originate from people unfamiliar with Windows/Active Directory.

Comment: Thanks for you reply Greg.